# rename regex not working in cygwin

Tags: regex, cygwin, rename, file-rename

I am using cygwin under windows 7.
In my directory there are files like

`fort.100 
 fort.101
 ...
 fort.1xx`

I want to give them all an extension `_v1`.
When I try to achieve it using `rename` by

`rename 's/$/_v1/' fort.*`

the prompt exit with no errors and **nothing happens**.
I then tried

`rename -e 's/$/_v1/' fort.*`, an error pops up,
`rename: unknown option -- e`

I also tried with a different delimiter `@` instead of `/` with no luck.

Now, I thought it was due to the character `_` in the expression (I am a newbie to `regex`), I tried escaping it by `\_` with no luck either. Again a try without `_`, for example,

`rename 's/$/v11/' fort.*` - nothing happens again.

Although I achieved my goal by

`for file in fort.*; do mv $file $file\_v1; done`, I wonder why `rename` doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because I am on cygwin?

Comment: Try `rename -E 's/$/_v1/' fort.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't work, exit with error `rename: unknown option -- E`.

Comment: If you do a `man rename` , is it a busybox light version of the binary or is it the original binay?

Comment: @Esteban It is not a busybox light version. `rename from util-linux 2.25.2
` It is as is from util-linux as far as I understand. Downloaded and compiled from standard cygwin repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround.
I replaced the `util-linux rename` to `perl rename` a separate package.
This was provided from [@subogero](https://github.com/subogero/rename) from `GitHub`.
All the usual `rename` expressions is working.

Answer (score 1):

The manual of `rename` does not match your expectations.
I see no regex capability.

```
SYNOPSIS
       rename [options] expression replacement file...

DESCRIPTION
       rename  will  rename  the specified files by replacing the first occur‐
       rence of expression in their name by replacement.

OPTIONS
       -v, --verbose
              Give visual feedback which files where renamed, if any.

       -V, --version
              Display version information and exit.

       -s, --symlink
              Peform rename on symlink target

       -h, --help
              Display help text and exit.

EXAMPLES
       Given the files foo1, ..., foo9, foo10, ..., foo278, the commands

              rename foo foo0 foo?
              rename foo foo0 foo??

       will turn them into foo001, ..., foo009, foo010, ..., foo278.  And

              rename .htm .html *.htm

       will fix the extension of your html files.
```

for what you want to reach the easy way is:

```
for i in fort*; do mv ${i} ${i}_v1 ; done
```

Comment: All that you had described is exactly the question I posed. I wanted to know why and how to make it work. And also, I had provided in the question the same script you mentioned.

Comment: The `why` is as the rename manual says. That functionality does not exist in the version provided in cygwin.